# Including style tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to include style tag in the javascript. ie., I am printing notices and the number of notices change dynamically. I receive the notices in a JSON object and hence require styles to be applied to each notice separately.

For now I just want the border around each notice or text

```js
function retrive()
   {
    /*var css = ' { border :2px dashed; }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';  Not working*/
    
    var myObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Notice"));
    if(myObj.length == 0)
    {
     $('#title').append(
      '<br><br>Currently There are no Notices to be displayed'
     );
    }
    
    else
    {
     for(var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++)
     {
      $('#heading').append(
       '<br><br><strong><center>'+ myObj[i].title+'</center></strong><br>'+myObj[i].introtext
      );
     }
    }
   }
```

I am printing the notices in the else block using for loop by finding the object length and appending it to the heading. This is where I want to print border to be printed around each block

```html
<div>
 <ul id="heading" style = "font-size : 16px;">
     
 </ul>     
</div>
```

If I use style here, border is appears to whole block or a single border to all notices.

```html
<div>
 <ul id="heading" style = "font-size : 16px; border : 2px dashed">
     
    </ul>     
</div>
```

,which is obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: The CSS you are adding to the head isn't working because you aren't selecting any element eg : `var css = ' #heading { border :2px dashed; }'` you could also use jquery [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to adjust the styles.

Comment: ok sir. How should i include or append it to the heading block in else block?

Comment: Isn't `<br>` deprecated. I would not do styling in java script makes it difficult to revamp websites

Comment: I think you'd be much better off creating some classes with the appropriate style definitions then apply the correct class dynamically to each element or container.  It's even possible that you could handle this entirely with CSS if your styles lay out depending on the position of the item in the list.  Also, `ul` should contain `li` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you could handle this entirely with CSS and applicable classes. If you need to make changes based on the number of items, you could define classes for the different sets of count values that would result in the same CSS settings and simply apply that class to the header.  Based on what you have in your code, that doesn't look to be the case and the example below should approximate what you're trying to achieve.

Note: I'm assuming that you're using a standard [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove list styles.  If not, then I suggest that you should.

```
<style>
#title p {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

#heading {
   font-size: 16px;
}

#heading li {
   border: 2px dashed;
}

#heading li span.item_title {
   font-weight: bold;
   display:  block;
   text-align: center;
}

#heading li span.item_text {
   display: block;
}
</style>
```

```js
function retrive()
{

    var myObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Notice"));
    if(myObj.length == 0)
    {
        $('#title').append('<p>Currently There are no Notices to be displayed</p>' );
    }
    else
    { 
        for(var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++)
        {
             $('#heading').append('<li><span class="item_title">'+ myObj[i].title+'</span><span class="item_text"'+myObj[i].introtext+ "</span></li>" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS classes you will be able to change the design more easily later, by modifying the CSS, rather than the JavaScript and HTML.

```
<style>
.heading
{ font-size : 16px; border : 2px dashed; }
</style>
<div>
    <ul id="heading" class="heading">
       ...
    </ul>                   
</div>
```

You can put the HTML in your JavaScript as you already have it, and use as many classes as you need.

In addition, try to avoid using <strong> and <br> and use CSS to control the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `css` style to each notice inside of `#heading`.

Something like this should work fine (place this in your css file or inside of a `style` tag) :

```
#heading strong {
  border: 2px dashed;
}
```

I would recommend surrounding each notice in a `span` and append this to your `#heading` inside of an `li` and then applying this style:

```
#heading li {
 list-style:none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#heading li span {
    border: 2px dashed;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

you html would look something like this:

```
<ul id='heading'>
  <!-- your newly inserted notice -->
  <li><span>text</span></li>
</ul>
```

This will remove the need for the `center` and `br` tags.